# How to extract date value from datetime string and transform into date format based on specific field in test file

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime-format

My input in file consists below text:

```
"Tested on: wed Mar 31 09::34:00 CST 2021 "
```

Looking to extract date field after this bit of text "Tested on:" and convert into date value in "dd/mm/yyyy" format e.g 31/Mar/2021
Used below regex, but getting error when doing:

```
import re  
import os
import dateparser

basepath = (r"C:\Users\xyz\test")
with os.scandir(basepath) as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        if entry.is_file():
            fn = entry.name
def f(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        for s in f:
    m = re.search(r'Tested on: \S+ (\S+) (\d+) \d+::\d+:\d+ AET (\d+)', s)
    subst = "\\2 \\1 \\3"
    result = re.sub(m, subst, s, 0, re.MULTILINE)
    if result:
        #Using strptime
        dt = dataetime.strptime(result.group(1), '%B %d %Y')
        dt_out = dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        return (fn, dt_out)
    else:
        return None

if __name__=="__main__":
    folder = (r"C:\Users\xyz\test/")
    _, _, filenames = next(os.walk(basepath))
    dates = []
    #dateparser.parse(dates = [])
    
    for i in filenames:
        print(f(folder + i), dates)
```

Above code return `attributerror - 'str' object has no attribute 'group'`.
regex doesn't work here. Seems, need to map each month into respective numbers, like march --> 3.

Comment: This is the second question you wrongfully tag `python-requests`. When you hover over a tag, a little box with its usage guidance appears. Please read those before applying tags. The one for [[tag:python-requests]] clearly says: *"USE ONLY FOR THE PYTHON REQUESTS LIBRARY. Requests is a full-featured Python HTTP library with an easy-to-use, logical API"*

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` returns a string, that's why you can't use `.group()` on it.

Normally `result` should return the string you want so you can just remove the `.group(1)` and change the format string accordingly to result
so the line would be `dt = datetime.strptime(result, '%d %b %Y')`

Comment: If i just use  result as below   then it throws valueError.                                                                                                    dt = dataetime.strptime(result, '%B %d %Y')
         dt_out = dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
         return (fn,dt_out)                                                                                                
 ValueError : time data 'Tested on : Wd Mr 31 09:54:41 CST 2021\n' doesnot match format '%b %d %y'

Comment: given your subst variable, your result willbe '31 Mar 2021 ' so you should then change the format string to '%d %b %Y'